# inject CSS link into head prior to existing CSS link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to inject some CSS into the head using link tags. I can get this to work pretty easily using

```
var linkNode = document.createElement('link');
linkNode.href = '"+ jqueryTablesorterCSS_URL +"';
linkNode.type = 'text/css';
linkNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
documentHead.appendChild(linkNode);
```

However I would like to have another already existing link tag be the last item in the head as it needs to take precedence. I do not have control over this other link tag and it already exists on the page.

Moving the other element by finding it like this does not seem to work.

```
var documentHead = document.head;
var customCSSNode = documentHead.querySelector("link[href$='custom.css']");
documentHead.appendChild(customCSSNode);
```

Comment: As a side note, when you inject using js, the other one would have been already loaded by the browser, so making it before won't change anything.

Comment: Maybe you could also do it by putting the CSS/JS links into the head section and just default set it as disabled and just handle enabling/disabling it via javascript?

Comment: It's correct that I don't really care about the order so much as the precedence order of the various CSS files. Normally this is controlled by order upon page load. Appending new files causes them to load and be applied. The same does not seem to be true if you read a CSS file that has already been loaded. It does not reapply.

Comment: point is it's the order they load that counts...so yours will be last regardless of where you put it in the head

Answer (score 0):

I feel kind of gross for suggesting this as it seems "wrong", though also seems to work when I tested it.  I think if you wait for the load event on the new css you can reload the existing by adding it back to the the "head" with appendChild

**Note in this sandbox "head" is actually "body".**

You can manually play with the ordering of the two css files, but I believe the effect you want is correctly applied when this result shows a split background with a rose in the center/right.

If the rose is on the left or if the background is not a rose then I have failed.

You may need to open the demo in full screen.  Sorry these were two easily grabbed CSS files to try to replicate what you are after.

```js
var documentHead = document.body;
var existingNode = document.getElementById("existing");

var linkNode = document.createElement('link');
linkNode.type = "text/css";
linkNode.rel = "stylesheet";
linkNode.onload = function(){ documentHead.appendChild(existingNode); }
linkNode.href = "http://www.csszengarden.com/220/220.css";
documentHead.appendChild(linkNode);
```

```html
<link id="existing" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.csszengarden.com/120/120.css" />

<div>Success if background pink rose in center</div>
<div>Fail if background pink rose on left</div>
<div>fail if kind of blue hand print</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the sort of thing I was hoping for. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It seems to be working in the sandbox (at least for me).  Do you have two simple public CSS files we can test with?